# How to initialize weights of layers in a deep network randomly from Gaussian distribution?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, initialization, gaussian

I designed a deep network in Matlab. and I want to initialize the weights of layers randomly from Gaussian distribution, However, the available weights initializers in Matlab are: glorot,he,narrow-normal,zeros, ones. and there is no option to initialize the weights from Gaussian distribution. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Read the Wikipedia description of Gaussian distribution, and you will know which one is the one you want ;) Hint: its one of the ones you listed, you just dindn't realize its called differently.

Comment: @Ander ok. I realized that the best choice for me is "he" initializer. Thanks alot

Comment: Huh, not really sure. `normal` is Gaussian. Gaussian distributions real name is "normal distribution"....